# Manipulate the position of the number in an ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following HTML

```
<h1> Dummy title here</h1>
<ol>
<li>
<p>Dummy paragraph here with lots of lines...</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Another dummy paragraph with lots of lines...</p>
</li>
</ol>
```

And I want to style it like the image shown. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P382R.jpg

The problem is that I cannot find a way to bring the numbers down to the paragraphs level. Instead they start from each paragraph's first line and I end up with an unwanted result.

Any guidance please?

**

### EDIT

**

I believe I have come up with a possible solution, not 100% compliant with the standards as I use a pseudo-class but still it is a viable solution. So here it is.

Using the structure exactly as I described it in my question I have come up with the following CSS

```
ol {
list-style: none;
}
ol li {
counter-increment: item;
}
ol p:before {
content: counter(item);
font-size: 80px;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

As sandeep requested, here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sm8AT/

Comment: a http://jsfiddle.net example is good to understand

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is this.  Style your ordered list with a very large font so that the numbers have a large font.  Then style the paragraph within with a much smaller font.  Something like this:

```
ol { font-size: 22px; }
ol p { font-size:  9px; }
```

Haven't tested this, but just a suggestion.  You may also need to play around with the positioning of the paragraph as well.

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't make any difference unfortunately. I've tried messing around with the number's position, since I can't really find a semantic way to bring the paragraph higher than its normal position, but I cannot seem to target the number ONLY because everything applied to the number, also applies to the paragraph.